# Html config of Extjs panel not be able to load script

Tags: extjs

I am trying to load script from html config of panel of extjs.

Here is My Code.

```
xtype: 'panel',
html:'<div id="myId'></div> <script> here is my code that load graph on myid</script>'
```

but code is loaded in file but it will not affect the myId div.
Any way to implement this kind of thing in extjs.

Comment: You want some code which will load data into panel's html.Then why dont you use loader config of panel ? Or you want some other kind of strategy.

Comment: When you are using JavaScript to generate HTML then why you are using script tag at all. Write the JavaScript  code in ExtJS itself.

Comment: i Need to use zoomchart in ext js .I am writing zoom chart code in <script> tag.

Comment: In initcomponent of your code write ajax call to fetch html & then render that html inside that div. Does this help your question ?